# How to avoid duplicate values from the url with faceted search?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, faceted-search

Standard feceting example from django-haystack documentation. I use FacetedSearchView and FacetedSearchForm.

Provided links:

```
age
20 (4)
18 (2)
21 (2)
22 (2)
24 (2)

price
200 (8)
150 (6)
100 (2)
300 (2)
400 (2)
```

When I chooses a link `20 (4)`, will narrow the search query to only include those conditions and display the further facets.

Provided URL: `?q=+&selected_facets=age_exact:20`

Provided links:

```
age
20 (4)
18 (0)
21 (0)
22 (0)
24 (0)

price
150 (2)
200 (2)
100 (0)
300 (0)
400 (0)
```

Until then, it's ok.

Once again, when I chooses a link `20 (4)`, will display the same facets but 
to the URL will add the same value: `?q=+&selected_facets=age_exact:20&selected_facets=age_exact:20`

...and so on 
`?q=+&selected_facets=age_exact:20&selected_facets=age_exact:20&selected_facets=age_exact:24&selected_facets=age_exact:21&selected_facets=age_exact:20&selected_facets=age_exact:18`

How to avoid adding new `&selected_facets=age_exact:` instead of changing the current value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but ensure that the link's 'href' property is set correctly. As an example, let's assume you are using `FacetedSearchView` and `FacetedSearchForm`: the link bellow would work just fine(like the doc example http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html):

```
<a class="facet" href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&selected_facets=age_exact:{{age.0|urlencode}}">{{ age.0 }}</a>
```